# Kendo grid sorting after inserting new data

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I'm having a trouble with kendo grid sorting after add new data to current grid datasource. I add new data to datasource this way:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(updateModel),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("SonKayitGetir")',
        success: function (data) {
            var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
            for (i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                data[i].KayitYaratmaTarihi = kendo.parseDate(data[i].KayitYaratmaTarihi, "HH:mm:ss - dd/MM/yyyy");
                data[i].KayitYaratmaTarihi = kendo.toString(data[i].KayitYaratmaTarihi, "HH:mm:ss - dd/MM/yyyy");
                grid.dataSource.insert(0, data[i]);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Auto Refresh failed...');
    }
});
```

I'm using Insert method because if i use `dataSource.Add()` i should use `datasource.Read()` after that. But i don't want go back to controller. Although I insert new data, it seems kendo grid sort function doesn't see new data.. It works with old data. How can i solve this problem? Is there another way to add new data to `datasource` without calling `dataSource.read()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be in jason structure

You may try this

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {    

    var ins = { Name1:kendo.parseDate(data[i].KayitYaratmaTarihi, "HH:mm:ss - dd/MM/yyyy") , Name2:kendo.toString(data[i].KayitYaratmaTarihi, "HH:mm:ss - dd/MM/yyyy")  }; 

    grid.dataSource.insert(ins);
}
```

i hope this may help you :)